# Relative imagemagick transforms: Relative Crop?

Tags: imagemagick

I'm trying to execute the following set of transformations without knowing the absolute width or height of the target image:

`1. Crop image A by 10px on every size :: A1
2. Create duplicate of A1 translating image by 1270px on the y-axis :: A2
3. Create montage of A1 && A2 :: A3
4. Translate A3 by 385px on the y-axis :: A4
5. Crop A4 at 100% width, and 1270px tall (box from 0,0 to WIDTH,1270) :: A5`

My issue is how do I do steps 1 and 5 with relative coordinates?  Below are my steps that I've come up with:

`1. convert A.jpg -shave 10x10 A1.jpg
2. convert A1.jpg -page +0-1270 -background none -flatten A2.jpg
3. montage A1.jpg A2.jpg -geometry +0+0 A3.jpg
4. convert A3.jpg -page +0-385 -background none -flatten A4.jpg
5. convert A4.jpg ????? A5.jpg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Ok, I think I understand what you want a bit better now. Here's how I would do it:

```
convert start.jpg -crop +0+383 +repage \
   \( -clone 0 -crop x1270+0+0    \)   \
   \( -clone 0 -crop x1270+0+1270 \)   \
   -delete 0 +append result.jpg
```

The first line says...*"Take the starting image and crop off the top 383 pixels and reset all the sizes to match what is left. Call that the first image from now onwards."*

The second line says...*"To one side (because of the parentheses), clone the first image and crop out the full width and 1270 pixels in height from the top. Hold onto that till later - i.e. keep it in the image list."*.

The third line says...*"To one side (because of the parentheses), clone the first image, and crop out a piece the full width and 1270 pixels in height, but start 1270 pixels from the top. Hold onto that till later - i.e. keep it in the image list."*

The last line says...*"Delete the initial image, and then take the two slices in the image list and append them side-by-side, Save as `result.jpg`"*.

**Original Answer**

I think we will need to work together on this one, but it can be done. Let's start with a concrete image that is a 400x250 gradient with a 15px black border:

```
convert -size 250x400 gradient:red-cyan -rotate 90 -bordercolor black -border 15 A.png
```

[image]

So, step 1.

```
convert A.png -shave 10x10 A1.png
```

[image]

Step 2&3. I don't get the point of these! You appear to be trying to add transparent space to a JPEG which doesn't support transparency. Also, I can't tell what you are montaging where. Please try and express what you want with these two steps in plain English, like *"add a transparent area N pixels wide/tall above/below, left/right of A2"*, or maybe *"add a transparent area such that the new dimensions are X,Y and the original A2 image is at the bottom-right of the new canvas."*

If I have a *stab* at steps 2&3, I'll guess this (and add a purple border so you can see it on StackOverflow's white background). I am appending a transparent area 1270 pixels tall below the image.

```
convert A.png -background none -shave 10x10 xc:none[1x1270\!] -append b.png
```

[image]

Step 4&5. As above.

Or maybe you mean this:

```
convert A.png -background magenta -shave 10x10 -gravity southeast -extent 1270x385 result.png
```

[image]

I think we can get you down to a single command, with no intermediate files, if we understand your needs.

Comment: Yeah, sorry -- was trying to make the question more generic, but obviously specifics help.  I'm trying to take this image https://static.neregate.com/2016/12/neregate.com-LQ-Winter-2016-2017-Anime-Chart-v3.jpg and turn it into https://markphilpot.com/images/anime/2017/winter/hero.jpg via script rather than by hand. Hope that adds some context. Essentially, I want to take the first 6 rows and montage/transpose them so it's 3 rows, 8 columns.

Didn't know about the -shave parameter!

Comment: It also sounds like the `-background none -flatten` parameters are not needed since I'm not dealing with a png?